# Angular4でエラーが出ている

Tags: angular4

Angular4で勉強中です。
@angular/cliを使用して、「ng new testApp」を実施して空のアプリを作成しました。

npm install
ng serve --open

うえのコマンドを実施して、ブラウザにサンプルが表示されることは確認できたのですが、
デベロッパーツールを見ると、コンソールにエラーが出ていました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ローカルのアプリフォルダを見ると、以下のnode_modulesディレクトリ配下には「@angular」
ディレクトリはあるものの「angular」がありません。
C:\Users\～～\angular_test\testApp\node_modules

npm installのコマンドで取得できるものと思っていたのですが、異なるのでしょうか？
◇index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script> 
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script> 
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script> 
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

◇package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: `ng new testApp`の過程で`npm install`は実行されるので、自分でやる必要はないはずです。自分も`@angular/cli(1.4.3)`を試してみましたが、正常に動いており、`node_modules`ディレクトリに`@angular`があるのが正常だと思います。`index.html`にある`<app-root>`の上の4つの`<script>`は自分で追加されたものですか？

Comment: はい。自分で追加しました。追加は不要なのですね。試してみます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

karamarimoさまのご指摘どおり、以下のように修正することで、エラーが消えることを確認できました。
＃正確には
＃@angular/cliを使用して、「ng new testApp2」を実施して空のアプリを作成し、
＃今回はindex.htmlには何も手を加えませんでした。
＃npm install
＃ng serve --open

◇index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestApp2</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

追加していた以下については必要ないのでしょうか？
追記しなくとも確かに表示されています。コンソールエラーも出ていませんでした。
本＆サイトを見ながら、やっていたのですが、てっきり、以下は必須のものなのかと思っていました。（後半のscriptはangular-materialを使用するために必要なのかと…）
package.jsonに記載し、npm installさえ実施していれば不要なのでしょうか…

```
    <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script> 
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script> 
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script> 
  <app-root></app-root>
```

Comment: 回答ではないので元の質問文を編集する形で追加したほうがいいですね。それはさておき、クライアントから見えるのはソースファイル`src/index.html`ではなく、angularがビルドしてできる`index.html`ファイルです。ビルドの過程でangularのライブラリや自分が書いたアプリケーションのコードはバンドルされて、`<script>`が追加された`index.html`ができあがります。`ng build`を実行すると`dist`フォルダーにビルドされたファイルが作られますので、中身を確認してみるといいでしょう。`ng serve`ではビルドしたファイルはメモリ上に作られ、保存されませんので、あくまで開発用の機能です。頻繁にアップデートが行われているので本の情報などあまり当てにせず[公式の説明](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)を見ることをおすすめします。

Comment: karamarimoさまありがとうございます。とても勉強になりました。さっそく、ng buildを実行してみると、distフォルダが作成されていました。中身をみると、<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.78cedb82027e85dc058d.bundle.js">などが追加されており、圧縮されたbundle.jsがdistフォルダはいかにできていました。勉強になりました！